# Unable to group by DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm trying to group by the following datatable:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| ID_OR | TIPO_OR | ORA_OR              | SENT_OR | ID_OR_CFG | ID_ART | TIPO_ART | COD_ART      | QTA_ART | ID_OR_ART | COD_VAR | ID_ART_VAR |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 132    | PLUREP   | CAFFE        | 1       | 40        |         |            |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 133    | PLUREP   | REPARTO 0019 | 1       | 40        |         |            |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 134    | PLUREP   | REPARTO 0018 | 1       | 40        |         |            |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 135    | PLUREP   | REPARTO 0037 | 1       | 40        |         |            |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 136    | PLUREP   | CAFFE        | 1       | 40        | VAR0001 | 136        |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 136    | PLUREP   | CAFFE        | 1       | 40        | VAR0002 | 136        |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
| 40    | MENU    | 10/06/2020 15:56:47 | 0       | 1         | 136    | PLUREP   | CAFFE        | 1       | 40        | VAR0003 | 136        |
+-------+---------+---------------------+---------+-----------+--------+----------+--------------+---------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

The data in datatable is got from MySQL, the table represents the order info, items, and variants of items, so I'm trying to build a list of orders that has in it it's items which has it's variants in it.

First of all I need to group the datatable by `ID_OR` which equals to order ID, so I was trying to do the following `var ordini = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR"));` but it has no effect, the  iteration through ordini was anyway iterating through all datatable rows... and then inside the ordini iteration I was trying to iterate throw the items of each order by still grouping them by `ID_ART` but even that group by has no effect and just added three times the item with `ID_ART` 136 three times in the list.

The whole code where I'm building the list of orders looks like the following:

```
var ordini = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR"));
foreach(var ordine in ordini)
{
    int id_ordine = ordine.Key;
    foreach (DataRow ro in ordine)
    {
        List<Ordine.Articoli> list_articoli = new List<Ordine.Articoli>();
        var articoli = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR_ART") == id_ordine).GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_ART"));
        foreach(var articolo in articoli)
        {
            int id_articolo = articolo.Key;
            foreach (DataRow ra in articolo)
            {               
                List<Ordine.Varianti> list_varianti = new List<Ordine.Varianti>();
                var varianti = articolo.Where(r => r.Field<int?>("ID_ART_VAR") == id_articolo);
                foreach (DataRow rv in varianti)
                {
                    list_varianti.Add(new Ordine.Varianti(rv.Field<string>("COD_VAR"), id_articolo));
                }
                list_articoli.Add(new Ordine.Articoli(id_articolo, ra.Field<string>("TIPO_ART"), ra.Field<string>("COD_ART"), ra.Field<float>("QTA_ART"), ra.Field<int>("ID_OR_ART"), list_varianti));
            }
        }
        list_ordini.Add(new Ordine(id_ordine, ro.Field<string>("TIPO_OR"), ro.Field<DateTime>("ORA_OR"), Convert.ToBoolean(ro.Field<ulong>("SENT_OR")), ro.Field<int>("ID_OR_CFG"), list_articoli));
    }
}
```

And the return value of that in json is the following:

```
[{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]},{"id":40,"tipo":"MENU","dataora":"2020-06-10T15:56:47","sent":false,"cfg":1,"articoli":[{"id":132,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":133,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0019","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":134,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0018","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":135,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"REPARTO 0037","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]},{"id":136,"tipo":"PLUREP","cod":"CAFFE","qta":1,"id_ordine":40,"varianti":[{"cod":"VAR0001","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0002","id_articolo":136},{"cod":"VAR0003","id_articolo":136}]}]}]
```

While it has to create just 1 array item with all items inside it...

**So the question is how to correctly group by a datatable?**

Comment: Why don't do that on DB side, e.g. write an sql query and return a required representation of the data?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski initially i was doing it by writing the sql query, but i have to run multiple selects (SELECT for all order then loop throw all orders and SELECT it's item and then loop throw all items and SELECT it's variants) and i tought that by using datatable it would be better for the performance so i just joined the three tables and filled them in datatable

Comment: From : var varianti = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int?>("ID_ART_VAR") == id_articolo);  To : var varianti = articolo.Where(r => r.Field<int?>("ID_ART_VAR") == id_articolo);  You do not need to enumerate through entire DataTable.  articoli is a List<DataRow>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that i have to use `.Select` after `.GroupBy` and to copy the grouped dt in a new one, so the code where `.GroupBy` is used from

```
var ordini = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR"));
```

now looks like this:

```
        var ordini = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR"))
            .Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

And i've changed the whole code by reducing the foreach to 3 instead of previous 5 as i could instantly use `DataRow` in ordini:

```
var ordini = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR"))
    .Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
foreach (DataRow ordine in ordini.Rows)
{
    int id_ordine = (int)ordine["ID_OR"];
    List<Ordine.Articoli> list_articoli = new List<Ordine.Articoli>();
    var articoli = dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<int>("ID_OR_ART") == id_ordine)
        .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID_ART"))
        .Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
    foreach (DataRow articolo in articoli.Rows)
    {
        int id_articolo = (int)articolo["ID_ART"];
        List<Ordine.Varianti> list_varianti = new List<Ordine.Varianti>();
        var varianti = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<int?>("ID_ART_VAR") == id_articolo);
        foreach (DataRow variante in varianti)
        {
            list_varianti.Add(new Ordine.Varianti((string)variante["COD_VAR"], id_articolo));
        }
        list_articoli.Add(new Ordine.Articoli(id_articolo, (string)articolo["TIPO_ART"], (string)articolo["COD_ART"], (float)articolo["QTA_ART"], (int)articolo["ID_OR_ART"], list_varianti));
    }
    list_ordini.Add(new Ordine(id_ordine, (string)ordine["TIPO_OR"], (DateTime)ordine["ORA_OR"], Convert.ToBoolean((ulong)ordine["SENT_OR"]), (int)ordine["ID_OR_CFG"], list_articoli));
}
```